Getting Timeout Error When using OpenAI files API
batch- api docs : https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/batch/getting-started
I am running the following code :
client = OpenAI(
    api_key=key1,
    base_url=url1
)
batch_input_file = client.files.create(file=open("batchinput.jsonl", "rb"), purpose="batch")

I am able to create the client but on calling client.files.create as given above I am getting this error :
raise APITimeoutError(request=request) from erropenai.APITimeoutError: Request timed out.

It is jsonl (json lines extension )Yes , as given in docs of batch api .
